# Is there an equivalent to Redshift's ACCEPTINVCHARS option for an INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: amazon-redshift

There are many online articles that talk about solving the following error:

`String contains invalid or unsupported UTF-8 codepoints.
Bad UTF-8 hex sequence: a4 (error 3)`

Unfortunately they talk about solving this issue for the `COPY` command, however I get the same issue with an `INSERT INTO`.

The solution for the `COPY` command talks about using the `ACCEPTINVCHARS` option, however there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for the `INSERT INTO` statement.

If baffles me that there is no real concept of `NVARCHAR` in Redshift which would ultimately solve this problem, so I want to know if anyone else has come up with a good solution for dealing with inserting invalid characters using `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: are you inserting with values()?

Comment: Yes its basically an `INSERT INTO table VALUES (id, 'name', 'type');`

Comment: i suggest you remove the invalid characters at the point you generate those commands. Also it is very slow inserting this way, do you do many of these? if so you should examine the alternatives (copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no such support for something similar to `ACCEPTINVCHARS` in an `INSERT INTO` statement. The general practice of getting data into Redshift is via bulk insert anyway which is precisely where the `COPY` command is relevant. Redshift doesn't do well with small inserts.

Lesson learnt is avoid inserts altogether. Go with the `COPY` command.